# Re-write table update as set instead of iterative method

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a list of user email addresses, in a test Oracle database, which are currently all set to the same value. I want to replace these with unique entries, with a number of invalid addresses and null values mixed in. My table currently looks like this and is around 250k rows in total.(I've excluded the null and invalid entries to save some space)

```
+-------------+--------------------+
| employee_id |       email        |
+-------------+--------------------+
|           1 | test@testemail.com |
|           2 | test@testemail.com |
|           3 | test@testemail.com |
|...          |...                 |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

And I'd like it to look like this

```
+-------------+---------------------+
| employee_id |        email        |
+-------------+---------------------+
|           1 | test1@testemail.com |
|           2 | test2@testemail.com |
|           3 | test3@testemail.com |
|...          |...                  |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

I've wrote the following PL/SQL to do the change, it works, but it's seems very inefficient. Can I use another method to take advantage of set processing?

Thanks for any help with this.

```
DECLARE
    i number(20);
    l_employee_id hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE;
    output_query varchar2(1000);
    CURSOR c_cursor IS
        SELECT employee_id
        FROM hr.employees;
PROCEDURE update_sql(id_num IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE, 
                     email IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    output_query := 'UPDATE hr.employees
                    SET email = '''|| email ||'''
                    WHERE employee_id = '|| id_num;
                    dbms_output.put_line(output_query); --for debug
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE output_query;
END;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_cursor;
    i := 1;
    <<outer_loop>>
    LOOP
        For j IN 1..5 LOOP
            FETCH c_cursor INTO l_employee_id;
            EXIT outer_loop WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;
            IF j <= 3 THEN
                update_sql(l_employee_id, ('test' || i || '@testemail.com'));
            ELSIF j = 4 THEN
                update_sql(l_employee_id, ('test' || i || 'testemail.com'));
            ELSIF j = 5 THEN
                update_sql(l_employee_id, ' ');
            END IF;
            i := i + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP outer_loop;
    CLOSE c_cursor;
END;
/
```

EDIT - 26/09/2016 - to clarify size of table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, even if you were going to code this iteratively, please don't use dynamic SQL where it is not necessary.  And it is only necessary if you don't know the table or columns you are going to be querying at compile time.

That said, it sounds like you just want

```
UPDATE employees
   SET email = (case when employee_id <= 3
                     then 'test' || employee_id || '@testemail.com'
                     when employee_id = 4
                     then 'test' || employee_id || 'testemail.com'
                     when employee_id = 5
                     then ' '
                     else null
                  end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My actual table has about 250k entries. Could I scale up this approach to work over a bigger table? I've edited my question as I can see this wasn't clear from what I've posted.

Comment: @DaveTurner - Sure.  Set-based updates will almost always scale better than iterative processing.  250,000 rows isn't much, I'd expect to be able to update that many rows in a few seconds on my laptop, probably less.  You can obviously adjust the `case` statement to have more/ different conditions.

Answer (score 5):

```
 create table emp (emp_id number, email varchar2(32));

 insert into emp select level as emp_id, 'test@testemail.com' as email 
 from dual connect by level<=2500000;

 update emp set email = regexp_replace(email, '(\w+)(@\w+\.\w+)', '\1' || emp_id || '\2');
 --250,000 rows updated ~16 sec.

EMP_ID, EMAIL
1   test1@testemail.com
2   test2@testemail.com
3   test3@testemail.com
...

drop table emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
create table employees (
  id    NUMBER,
  email VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO employees
SELECT 1, 'test@testemail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'test@testemail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'test@testemail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'test@testemail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'test@testemail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'test@testemail.com' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
update employees
set email = CASE MOD( ROWNUM, 5 )
            WHEN 4 THEN 'test' || ROWNUM || 'testemail.com'
            WHEN 0 THEN ''
                   ELSE 'test' || ROWNUM || '@testemail.com'
            END;
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM employees;

        ID EMAIL
---------- ------------------------
         1 test1@testemail.com
         2 test2@testemail.com
         3 test3@testemail.com
         4 test4testemail.com
         5 
         6 test6@testemail.com
```